# Generating a Crystal report containg a sub report through JAVA Program

Tags: java, web, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report with a sub report in it. I am passing the parameters to my Main report through a JSP/JPO.

Could you please help me how to pass the parameters to my sub-report without prompting for inputs from user.

one more information- The repost is called from a Web application.